# Rails Console - Why is "collection.delete(element)" deleting the element itself from database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I want to remove an element from a has_many relationship collection without destroying the element.

This works for me with this method:

```
current_user.flats.delete(Flat.find(7))
```

When I try to do a similar thing on the rails console, it destroys the whole object in the database:

```
irb(main):018:0> current_user.houses.delete(House.find(10))

SQL (13.4ms)  DELETE FROM "cities_houses" WHERE "cities_houses"."city_id" = ?  [["city_id", 10]]
SQL (0.8ms)  DELETE FROM "houses" WHERE "houses"."id" = ?  [["id", 10]]
```

As you can see, it removes the whole house object from it's own table.

What makes even less sense: It tries to remove an entry on the join table "cities_houses" using the given house_id (10) as parameter for the city_id to remove the element?

I don't get in general why it tries to update this join table. My command had nothing to do with it...

I'm using Rails version: 5.1.1 and Ruby version: 2.4.1 (x86_64-linux)

Comment: if it's a has_many through relationship then it makes perfect sense that it would delete the row in a join table that defines that association. can you post your models and schema for users, cities, houses, and cities_houses?

Comment: You've hit the point! It'S a has_many/bleongs_to rleationship. I just solved the problem and read your comment afterwards :)
Thank you! I've posted this as an answer.

But anyways, I thinks it's weird, that it doesn't throw an error, but updates other tables. Pretty dangerous in production mode...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution to solve the problem!

This doesn't work, when `dependent: :destroy` is enabled.

```
current_user.houses.delete(House.find(10))
```

The solution is pretty obvious: for a has_many/belongs_to-association, you can just update the value user_id of the flat to nil. I knew this way, but what I've tried first **didn't worked:**

```
House.find(10).user_id = nil
House.find(10).save
```

The updated value will be changed and the change is immediately forgotten, if it is not stored in a variable.

**This works:**

```
house = House.find(10)
house.user_id = nil
house.save
```

**Another solution, without loading the house model first:**

```
House.where(id: 10).update_all(user_id: nil)
```

Comment: Usually in a `has_many` `belongs_to` association doing `current_user.houses.delete(House.find(10))` would work, setting `user_id` on `house` to `null`. However if your `user` `has_many :houses, dependent: :destroy` then `current_user.houses.delete(House.find(10))` *will* destroy the `house`, which will subsequently destroy its `cities_houses` join table entries. Does your `User has_many :houses, dependent: :destroy`? If so, then you probably shouldn't be mixing that with `houses` that have `user_id = null`

Comment: I get it slowly. My user `has_many :houses, dependent: :destroy` indeed. This means: The house gets destroyed when the connection is removed, am I right? So it's not a bug - it's expected behavior...
Is it really not okay to have `dependent: :destroy` and `user_id = null` allowed? In my case a house is created without a `user_id`. Over time, a user can become its owner. When the user will be removed, the house should also get removed. Is it okay in this case or bad practice?

Comment: `House.where(id: 10).update_all(user_id: nil)` no need to load the record.

Comment: Great comment, I'll add this to my answer!